# Point In Time recovery on Mysql

Tags: mysql, percona, mysqlbinlog

Can someone please advise best methods to do a mysql PITR from binary logs that are saved in MIXED format.

I am finding it difficult to identify the wrong queries that executed to avoid from restore process using mysqlbinlog tool.

Following : https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/innobackupex/pit_recovery_ibk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inspect the binary log add `-vvv` to `mysqlbinlog`. It will show an effective query that corresponds to a binlog event.